# Is there a difference between using `PostQuitMessage` and just processing all messages?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I wonder whether there's a difference between those two snippets:

## One:

```
void main()
{
    // ...

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    ExitProcess(0);
}

// ...

void quit()
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
}
```

## Two:

```
bool quit = false;

void main()
{
    // ...

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        if(quit)
        {
            while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&_msg);
            }
            ExitProcess(0);
        }
    }

    // Shouldn't get here
    ExitProcess(1);
}

// ...

void quit()
{
    quit = true;
    PostThreadMessage(GetCurrentThreadId(), WM_NULL, 0, 0);
}
```

Sorry but I couldn't come up with shorter snippets.

The point of my question is whether calling `PostQuitMessage` and processing all messages with `GetMessage` is equivalent to processing all messages with `PeekMessage`, until it returns `FALSE`.

[According to Raymond](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/04/489028.aspx), `WM_QUIT` is "generated only when the message queue is otherwise empty", so it looks like the two methods should do the same, but perhaps there's a subtle difference.

Comment: Is this purely an intellectual curiosity or are you trying to achieve a particular effect with your non-standard approach?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I'm looking at a codebase of one guy who's using some non-standard programming style. In addition to this, he's reluctant to change the code unless really necessary. So I'm wondering whether what he did is at least correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raymond's blog post says:

> Because the system tries not to inject a WM_QUIT message at a "bad
>   time"; instead it waits for things to "settle down" before generating
>   the WM_QUIT message, thereby reducing the chances that the program
>   might be in the middle of a multi-step procedure triggered by a
>   sequence of posted messages.

So in theory no, there is no difference, because the system won't generate `WM_QUIT` until the queue is empty. However Raymond doesn't say that it's **guaranteed** that messages won't arrive after `WM_QUIT` is generated, only that the system **tries** to avoid it.

Therefore it's conceivably possible that another thread could post you a message after you've exited your main `GetMessage` loop, and depending on your application this may be something you have to deal with. For example, if you post messages internally with memory allocations that the receiving thread is expected to free, you may need a separate `PeekMessage` loop to clean them up before the thread exits completely.

In practice however no one ever writes message loops like your second example.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that in both examples, a message can be posted after the loop exited, and nothing can be done about it, but I thought that perhaps the special `WM_QUIT` does something that can't be done manually. P.S. the second example is something I've seen in a codebase, that's why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the accepted answer addresses the real issue.
Raymond answers this question directly [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050222-00/?p=36393).

Basically:

1. You do not have control over every message loop, so you don't have that option.
2. Oh, and by the way, don't forget to `PostQuitMessage` *inside your own message loops*.
   Note that [even WTL neglects to do this!](https://sourceforge.net/p/wtl/git/ci/363214b57a21331cce13ad62b7b836ca8513dc91/tree/Include/atlapp.h#l657)
   It relies on *you* passing the return value of `CMessageLoop::Run` to `PostQuitMessage`.